# Run Mono Application on Startup with a Service

Tags: 22.04, services, mono

When the ubuntu system boots up, my service that starts test.exe fails (using systemctl status Testprog.service):

```
at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor ()
at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance ()
at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor ()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles ()
at Testprog.Program.Main (System.String[] args)
```

The Testprog.service located at /lib/systemd/system/Testprog.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=test launcher
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service network.target syslog.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment="DISPLAY=:0" "XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0; mono test.exe"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the service manually (using systemctl restart Testprog.service) the program starts without errors but the test.exe does not start when the systems boots.

I don't see what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.